# Screen scraping advertisements shown in android apps

Tags: java, android, screen-scraping

I was googling about screenscraping android phones for advertisements that are shown while I run some apps in it. A service seems to be an option which can record the happenings on the screen. So my question is that how do I come to know that an advertisement is being shown by an app? Are there any api's provided by android OS which would give me an idea that an ad has been show by the app?

Any ideas regarding the same are welcome.

Comment: Generally Android keeps what apps are doing private from each other, so you'd need to either modify the Android installation to expose internal details (such as View manipulation methods called by code in packages corresponding to add SDKs), or use the debug screenshot capability (from an external debug host) to capture images and attempt to deduce if they contain ads.

Comment: "modify the Android installation to expose internal details" so any @ChrisStratton further details on how we can do this? Or is it possible at all?

Comment: Basically the same way people install custom ROMs (wit the same requirement for a developer device or "breaking into" a consumer one).  Replace basic UI API methods with ones that pattern match and log to some channel you can capture from a recording service. But if you just want to get an idea of what is possible, build your own example app with an ad SDK in it and a debug certificate and try out the method-call analytics tools in the Android debugger.

Comment: This might be able to be accomplished using the Accessibility APIs. You can request information about the Views in a Window, and possibly there is something unique about advertisements that you could look for (not sure what that would be).